# VSCode git integration not supporting git command options?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

VSCode git integration using f1 then git command does not seem to understand git options.

For example, when I try to type: `git branch -m newBranchName`, it completes it proposes me to create a branch called `m-NewBranchName` :(.

Is there anyway to pass options in git commands in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command palette does not parse additional arguments in any way.

But you can always open the built-in terminal. It starts in your current working directory, so you can just type away and it should work.